# How to freeze a worksheet in multiple ways in excel 2016?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I am looking to freeze the panes in an excel worksheet so that :

the top 10 rows and the left most 4 columns are frozen, i.e. only the bottom right portion of the worksheet moves.

I have tried using the split function but i don't want the data to be duplicated on the screen if someone moves right to the top or the left.

Answer (score 0):

1. Unfreeze Panes if they are frozen
2. Select E11 (11th row and 5th column)
3. Freeze Panes!

Comment: But this still moves the top portion of the screen if i move to the right.
I would always like the top 10 rows to always be in view and not move at all.